# Using "networks:" with molecule unit tests for Ansible roles

Tags: docker, redis, ansible, podman, molecule

I have a role that sets up a redis cluster.  This is your typical redis install with a master, replica and a sentinel running on three different hosts.

I have this molecule file:

```
(venvpy36) [russell.cecala@russells-vm default]$ cat molecule.yml
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: podman
platforms:
  - name: redis-master.example.com
    image: oraclelinux:9
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    command: "/usr/sbin/init"
    privileged: true
    pre_build_image: true
    groups:
      - cluster
      - newsp
    exposed_ports:
      - 6379
      - 26379
    networks:
      - name: podman
        links:
          - redis-replica.example.com
          - redis-sentinel.example.com

  - name: redis-replica.example.com
    image: oraclelinux:9
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    command: "/usr/sbin/init"
    privileged: true
    pre_build_image: true
    groups:
      - cluster
      - newsp
    exposed_ports:
      - 6379
      - 26379
    networks:
      - name: podman
        links:
          - redis-master.example.com
          - redis-sentinel.example.com

  - name: redis-sentinel.example.com
    image: oraclelinux:9
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    command: "/usr/sbin/init"
    privileged: true
    pre_build_image: true
    groups:
      - cluster
      - newsp
    exposed_ports:
      - 6379
    networks:
      - name: podman
        links:
          - redis-master.example.com
          - redis-replica.example.com


provisioner:
  name: ansible
  inventory:
    links:
      host_vars: ./inventory/host_vars
      group_vars: ./inventory/group_vars
verifier:
  name: ansible
```

When I run `molecule converge` and log on to each of the containers I find they all have the same IP address.

```
$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                           COMMAND         CREATED         STATUS             PORTS       NAMES
f757241cb210  container-registry.oracle.com/os/oraclelinux:9  /usr/sbin/init  24 minutes ago  Up 24 minutes ago              redis-master.example.com
ea5bfcb009dc  container-registry.oracle.com/os/oraclelinux:9  /usr/sbin/init  24 minutes ago  Up 24 minutes ago              redis-replica.example.com
e4d02d1bec29  container-registry.oracle.com/os/oraclelinux:9  /usr/sbin/init  24 minutes ago  Up 24 minutes ago              redis-sentinel.example.com
```

```
[root@redis-master /]# ip a | grep inet
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    inet 10.0.2.100/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global tap0
    inet6 fd00::3c58:e3ff:fe22:5597/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
    inet6 fe80::3c58:e3ff:fe22:5597/64 scope link
```

The other two containers have the same ...

```
[root@redis-replica /]# ip a | grep inet
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    inet 10.0.2.100/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global tap0
    inet6 fd00::6415:d7ff:fe99:97cd/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
    inet6 fe80::6415:d7ff:fe99:97cd/64 scope link
```

How can I get all three of the containers have different IPs and will they be able to connect to each other?